# Adding a JSON elements to an Array of JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have JSON and JSON array and I want to push every elements of JSON to JSON array with some condition.

Here is my code:

```
let json = { Jack: 10, Merry: 29, Charles: 37, Lahm: 0 }
let jsonArray = [
    {
        match: {
            Ashley: 46,
        },
    },
]

for (const key in json) {
    if (json[key] !== 0) {
        jsonArray.push({
            match: `{${key}: ${json[key]}}`,
        })
    }
}
```

I get the following response:

```
[
  { match: { Ashley: 46 } },
  { match: '{Jack: 10}' },
  { match: '{Merry: 29}' },
  { match: '{Charles: 37}' }
]
```

The problem is that pushed elements has single quotes which I don't want.
Is there a way to push those elements without quotes?

Comment: There is no JSON here. Just JS arrays and objects.

Comment: Specifically, JSON is always a single string whose content is of a certain format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the key/value pairs of the JS object, and not add a string to the array. Once that's completed for all the properties - if you need to - you can then stringify the array to JSON.

```js
const obj = { Jack: 10, Merry: 29, Charles: 37, Lahm: 0 };
const arr = [ { match: { Ashley: 46 } }];

for (const key in obj) {
  arr.push({
    match: { [key]: obj[key] }
  });
}

console.log(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that you're not really working with JSON. JSON is a *string representation* of JavaScript objects. What you have is simply a plain JS object, and also an array of objects.

Your issue is that you're simply passing a string into `match`, and not an actual object, when you are using template literals.

Instead, use bracket notation to use the value of the `key` variable in your new `match` object, i.e.:

```
match: { [key]: json[key] }
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
let myObject = {
  Jack: 10,
  Merry: 29,
  Charles: 37,
  Lahm: 0
}
let myArrayOfObjects = [{
  match: {
    Ashley: 46,
  },
}, ]

for (const key in myObject) {
  if (myObject[key] !== 0) {
    myArrayOfObjects.push({
      match: {
        [key]: myObject[key]
      }
    })
  }
}

console.log(myArrayOfObjects);
```

---

This is also a good chance to explore the use of `Object.entries`, since it actually returns the a `[key, value]` tuple:

```js
let myObject = {
  Jack: 10,
  Merry: 29,
  Charles: 37,
  Lahm: 0
}
let myArrayOfObjects = [{
  match: {
    Ashley: 46,
  },
}, ]

Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value !== 0) {
    myArrayOfObjects.push({
      match: {
        [key]: value
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(myArrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are pushing an object with a template string in it to the array. You need to change the syntax a little bit.

```
for (const key in json) {
    if (json[key] !== 0) {
        jsonArray.push({
            match: {[key]: json[key]}
        })
    }
}
```